# How to clear text from search menu android

Tags: android, eclipse, searchview

I've created a search in my application. Also database and contant provider. When I click on the term in the search, then starts an activity that leads to  explanation of this term. When I go back to the previous activity, the text is still visible in the search box. I'd like to be automatically cleared.

I was looking for solution to the problem, but I have not found it. Please help!

SearchableDictionary.java

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.searchable_dictionary, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

        SearchView searchView = SearchView)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchableInfo info = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(info); 
        searchView.setIconified(true);
```

I tried with:   searchView.clearFocus(); searchView.setQuery("", false); but it  did not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onCreateOptionsMenu` will most likely not be called when you go back to the previous activity as unless there are memory constraints the activity will not be killed and restarted.

I would recommend calling `searchView.setQuery("", false)` in the callback when the user clicks on a result. Then start the new Activity and when the user returns the search field will already have been cleared.